# Why isn't this div with background-image inside table-cell displaying at all?

Tags: html, css, height, background-size

**[JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/tpu10dxu/1/)**

Why doesn't `.col-left-bg-image` display at all?

---

I just realized that it is not displaying because it does not have any content inside it. So I checked by putting `...` into it and giving it a `background-size:100% 100%` (Initially it was `auto 100%`). But as a result, the div with the `background-image` is displayed, but it does not take a `height` of 100% of the parent (i.e. `.col-left`) :s **[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tpu10dxu/4/)**

---

I also tried to use an inline `img` element instead of a `div` with `background-image`, but that results in disaster. **[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ux5puf6k/)**.

```css
@import url(<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,300,600,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>);
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.section-big { /* change the width/height here */
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
 margin:100px auto 25px;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
}
.col-left-bg-image {
    background: url("http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/7a01/xaagjmwa7yz1dgdzg.jpg?size_id=b") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.col-left {
 padding:0px 25px;
}



.col h3, .col h5 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.col section:nth-child(1) {
    height: 30%;
}
.col section:nth-child(2) {
    height: 22%;
}
.col section:nth-child(3) {
    height: 22%;
}
.col section:nth-child(4) {
    height: 26%;
}
.col section:nth-child(odd) {
    background: aqua;
}
.col section:nth-child(even) {
    background: lime;
}



h3 {
 color:#6c6969;
 transition:color 0.3s ease 0s;
 font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:600;
 font-size:40px;
}

h5 {
 color:#6c6969;
 transition:color 0.3s ease 0s;
 font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-big">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col col-left">
   <div class="col-left-bg-image"></div>
            <!-- <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/9642/57q0fpdevvo1999zg.jpg?size_id=b" alt="Tun Tun!" /> -->
        </div>
        <div class="col col-right">
            <section class="section-one">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
            <section class="section-two">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
            <section class="section-three">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
            <section class="section-four">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Set height to the element https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/tpu10dxu/5/

Comment: @MrLister The `.col-left` div also has a class of `col` which has a height of 100%. Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was confused. Everything has a height in %, but since that goes all the way up to `html`, it all boils down to the height of the window. So Chris has got it right: you forgot to set the height of `col-left-bg-image` itself.

Comment: @lmgonzalves Hey this solves my problem, so thank you. Can you figure out a way to right-align the image div in its parent (`col-left` with `display:table-cell` property)? `text-align` or `align-content` doesn't seem to work :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete solution (with image align to right):

```
.col-left-bg-image {
    background: url("http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/7a01/xaagjmwa7yz1dgdzg.jpg?size_id=b") no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center right;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/tpu10dxu/7/

Answer (score 3):

I simply added 'height: 100%' to the 'col-left-bg-image' class in your second JSFiddle and it seemed to work fine. The 'background-size' of a div does not size up the same way an image would inside of a div. An image would have resized the div to fit it, making a background image does not :D

[JSFiddle Here!](https://jsfiddle.net/tpu10dxu/6/)

```
.col-left-bg-image {
    height: 100%;
    background: url("http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/7a01/xaagjmwa7yz1dgdzg.jpg?size_id=b") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Let me know if this was not what you meant :D

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. So thank you very much. I upvoted you answer and am thankful, but have to accept the other answer because they answered it earlier (in comments though)

Comment: I believe the guy below me got it. 'background-position: center right'. Just remember that backgrounds don't work like other elements or divs, its kinda like texturing the div. Backgrounds have separate style attributes to resize and reposition. There are other properties that will most likely help you in the future (like background-size: cover). :D Check out the W3 pages on [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) and [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-position.asp)

Comment: Thank you so very much for the insight, and I will surely give them a read =) Thank you again.